# Maximal Chains in a Poset

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let us say for two elements $x$ and $y$ of a poset, $y$ covers $x$ if $x < y$
and there is no $z$ such that $x < z < y$. Show that if $P$ is a finite poset with the longest chain
has length $l$ and if for any pair $y$ covering $x$ in $P$ there exists a chain of length $l$ containing
both $x$ and $y$, then every maximal (by inclusion) chain in $P$ has length $l$. Assume $P$ has
no isolated elements.

I am attempting to solve this problem using contradiction by assuming there is a maximal chain with length less than $l$ and proving that this would yield a chain with length larger than $l$ using the fact that two elements $x$ and $y$ where $y$ covers $x$ is contained in a chain with length $l$.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you could recall that an isolated element is an element that is both maximal and minimal? I would suggest you to try to build counter-examples and see what prevents you to do so. Start with some chain that you suppose maximal but of length $<l$ (each consecutive elements are covering) and for each pair of consecutive elements, look at what the hypothesis forces and try to fix the counter-example to make it hold.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to utilize the fact that isolated elements are not allowed. I thought this given part is only used to ensure that the graph does not have a maximal chain in P of length 1?

Comment: Yes, if $P$ has a maximal chain of length $1$ then we cannot use the hypothesis on it.

Comment: ohhh, i see. I wasn't aware you meant prove the statement by induction. Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't mean to prove the statement by induction, I mean to try to build a counter-example. If we have a maximal chain of some length $<l$, what does the hypothesis give you?

Comment: Anyway Brian M. Scott posted the solution I had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for answering though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKETCH: Suppose that $C$ is a maximal chain in $P$ of length less than $\ell$.

- Explain why $C$ has at least two elements.
- Show that if $n=|C|$, we can index $C=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ so that $x_{k+1}$ covers $x_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$.

For $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ let $C_k$ be a chain of length $\ell$ containing $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$, let $$C_k^{-}=\{y\in C_k:y\le x_k\}\;,$$ and let $$C_k^+=\{y\in C_k:x_{k+1}\le y\}\;.$$

Note that $|C_k^-|+|C_k^+|=\ell$.

- Use the maximality of $P$ to show that $|C_1^+|=\ell-1$.
- Use this to show that $|C_2^-|\le 2$ and hence that $|C_2^+|\ge\ell-2$. (Assume for now that $\ell$ is large enough for this to make sense.)
- Use this to show that $|C_3^-|\le 3$ and hence that $|C_3^+|\ge\ell-3$. (Again, assume for now that $\ell$ is large enough for this to make sense.)
- Recognize that this can be converted to a proof by induction that $|C_k^+|\ge\ell-k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, and do the conversion.
- Conclude that $|C_{n-1}^+|\ge\ell-n+1\ge 2$, so that $|C_{n-1}^-|=\ell-|C_{n+1}^-|\le\ell-2$.
- Use the maximality of $P$ to get a contradiction by showing that $|C_{n-1}^-|=\ell-1$.

Comment: I think you may have some typos at the end but this is a great answer thank you very much

Comment: @MatthewChoi: You’re welcome.

Comment: I actually have a question. Why does |C2-| have to be strictly less than three? Could there not exist another element y in P where y < x2?

Comment: Never mind, I just realized it's because of the maximal length of any chain is $l$. I am overthinking it.

Comment: @MatthewChoi: If $|C_2^-|\ge 3$, you could paste it together with $C_1^+$ to get a chain of length at least $2+\ell-1=\ell+1$, contradicting the definition of $\ell$. And I see that you caught it while I was typing. :-)